# Am I able to have a collection of Entities on another Entity using a manyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, entity-framework, collections, many-to-many, entitymanager

I have searched a couple posts here, as well as the eclipse wiki for relationship mapping but I continue to get the following error:

```
Exception Description: [class package.Class1] uses a non-entity [class package.Class2] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field list1].
```

What I've Tried:

```
@ManyToMany, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToOne
Collection, List, ArrayList
```

Class1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table_1")
public class Class1 {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "IdGen")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int _id;

@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "IdGen",
        sequenceName = "INC_ID",
        allocationSize = 1)

@Column(name = "Table_1_TYPE")
private int _typeId;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Table_1_TO_Table_2",
joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "ID"),
inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "CID"))
private List<Class2> list1;
```

Class2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table_2")
public class Class2 {

@Id
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Table_1_TO_Table_2",
joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "CID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"))
private int _id;

@Column(name = "Value")
private String _value;
```

My situation is multiple '*CIDs*' from **Table_2** can belong to a single '*ID*' from **Table_1**. My third table (their relational table) '**Table_1_TO_Table_2**' has two columns: ID and CID.

**Edit 2/13 - 9:30 :**
I also checked my persistence file and both classes were added to it. But the problem still occurs that Class2 is not recognized as an entity.

Comment: Are both entity classes recognized by JPA or do you get errors during startup? Can you query for `Class2` objects directly from your current setup? You also used different case (`table_` vs. `Table_` in you annotations), you better fix that as well.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: `Class2` has the `@ManyToMany` annotation for the id. That won't work. If you need a bidirectional mapping, you'll need to add a collection of `Class1` to `Class2` and annotate that with `@ManyToMany`. If all you need is an unidirectional mapping from `Class1` to `Class2`, then you can simply remove the `@ManyToMay` and `@JoinTable` annotations from `Class2`.

Comment: @duckstep Thanks for your response...I get errors during start up, and I didn't catch the case difference...I'll try removing those annotations from Class2...Thanks!

Comment: @duckstep I removed the annotations `@ManyToMany` as well as `@JoinTable` but the error returns. I've also tried using `implements serializable` on `Class2`.

Answer (score 0):

This programme contains multiple errors , I will explain them one by one

1. Non-Entity Class

> Exception Description: [class package.Class1] uses a non-entity [class
>   package.Class2] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field
>   list1].

Solution: Declare Class2 in hibernate.cfg.xml. Like

```
                <mapping class="com.test.dto.Class2"/>
```

2. Generate getter / setter of  list1 on Class1 so that you can instantiate class1 object and set class2's objects in this list
3. > Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown
   >   Id.generator: IdGen
   >   at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.makeIdGenerator(BinderHelper.java:638)

   Solution--> Move Sequence Generator above the field using it

   ```
             public class Class1 {
               @SequenceGenerator(name = "IdGen",sequenceName = "INC_ID",                      
                allocationSize = 1)

                   @Id
               @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  
                  generator="IdGen")   

           @Column(name = "ID")
             private int _id;
   ```
4. > Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal >attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or >@CollectionOfElements: com.test.dto.Class2._id
   >     at >org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBi>nder.java:327)
   >     at >org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.j>ava:1719)
   >     at >org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBi>nder.java:766)

Here you are trying to implement oneToMany Mapping it should be done like as below

```
    @Table(name = "Table_1")
         public class Class1 {
        ....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cid")
    private List<Class2> list1;

     @Table(name = "Table_2")
     public class Class2 {
     ...
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="cid")
     private Class1 cid;
```

5. > RootClass:289 - HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): >com.test.dto.Class2
   >   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class >must implement Serializable: com.test.dto.Class2

Solution Either implement Class2 with Serializable Interface or

Define Primary Key in Class2

```
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "Table_2")
      public class Class2 {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int class2Id;
```